# Is there any automatic way in MatLab for computing the gradient of a CNN wrt the inputs?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, automatic-differentiation

I have trained a shallow CNN using MatLab's Machine Learning Toolbox. The input of this CNN is an image and the output is an image too: *f(x) = y*, where *x* is the input image and *y* is the output image. The CNN simply reads as

*f(x) = ReLU(W * x + b)*

where *ReLU* is the rectified linear unit and * stands for the convolution.

I need to automatically compute the gradient of the CNN with respect to the input *x*: so far I tried

- the function [`fpderiv`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/fpderiv.html): but this computes the derivative of the performance with respect to the weights and the biases of the network.
- the function [`dlgradient`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/dlarray.dlgradient.html): this one is usually used to compute the gradient wrt weights and biases, so I naively tried to adapt it to compute the gradient wrt the inputs:

  `function gradients = nngrad(dlnet,a)`

  `a     = dlarray(single(a),'SSCB');`

  `a_pre = forward(dlnet,a);`

  `gradients = dlgradient(a_pre(1),dlnet.Layers(1));`

  `end`

calling the above function via `gradients = dlfeval(@nngrad,dlnet,A);`, where `dlnet` is a `dlnetwork` object. The above version computes the gradient wrt to the first element of the input image. I get the following error:

> Error using dlfeval (line 43)
> 'dlgradient' inputs must be traced dlarray objects or cell arrays, structures or tables
> containing traced dlarray objects. To enable tracing, use 'dlfeval'.

I checked in MatLab's documentation if there is some way to cast the `Layer` object into a `dlarray` or similar strategies, but I did not have any success.

Is there any way to correctly use the `dlgradient` function? Or is there any built-in function which allows to compute the gradient of a NN with respect to the input?

---

This is a very simple CNN, whose gradient can be computed with a little tensor algebra, but I am interested in finding a function which automatically computes the gradient wrt the inputs for deeper CNNs.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't cast `a` as a `dlarray` in the same function where you invoke `dlgradient`.
Try to pass `a` as a `dlarray` to `nngrad` instead of recasting.